# Virtual machine shows no network adapter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2000

I had a an old Lotus/Domino server (R5), I just virtualized. It ran Windows 2000 server. I had to use Vmware Converter v3.x to create the vm because it was the only one I could find that could actually do a Win2k machine that had no service packs. It was just put out to pasture a couple months ago, so it isn't being used except to store the old email for archiving. It took a bit of work to get it onto the Win2008R2 servers hyper-v but I got it there.

**EDIT: Forgot to mention I used [VMDK2VHD](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry8.aspx) to convert the vmdk to a vhd.**

Problem now, is that the network adapter didn't show up. I could not install the guest additions because it needed sp4 + on win2k... so I installed sp4 onto the vm guest.

Everything seems fine except the network adapter still isn;t showing up in device manager. NOthing. Now this server had an external ip, and I did not want it to be put onto the internal virtual network. I am going to use a dedicated adapter on the host (hyper-v server) if that matters... but this shouldn't matter if the the guests network adapter doesn't show at all.

Device Mananger "**show hidden devices**" I get the following:

[image]

I also loaded the vmdk file into VMWare PLayer, and no network adapters displayed. Results were the same as the image. So the problem isn't VMDK2VHD.

Thoughts?

Comment: So you converted it with the VMware converter and then put it on a Hyper-V host? How does that work? Why not put on a vSphere host or put it in VMware Player?

Comment: Because SCVMM is expensive, and probably wouldn't work anyway?

Comment: Are there **any** network adapters listed in the Windows 2000 Server guest under Device Manager? Have you looked into doing a V2V conversion (VMware -> Hyper-V) with a tool like [5nine V2V Easy Converter (FREE)](http://www.5nine.com/vmware-hyper-v-v2v-conversion-free.aspx)?

Comment: @joeqwerty... I will try using the vmdk with with VMware PLayer to see if the problem was with the vmdk2vhd conversion. @ mweisel... I will also try the app you mentioned too.

Comment: @mweisel... If I remember correctly there were no network adapters listed in Device Manager.  I can remote into the server but mouse does not work when I do otherwise I could check right now. And Alt-Tab does not seem to work on this server (when using rdp) so I cannot cycle through the windows to open the device manager.

Comment: I used VMWare PLayer to load the vmdk file before the vmdk2vhd comversion. Same result: No Network Adapters are displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you do not have a Legacy network adapter assigned to the VM in Hyper-V manager.